# How to use object.get() on an object we've just created

Tags: python, django

I'm newbie in Python/Django , I was trying to implement Django activity stream and I'm kind of stuck.

Here is my code :

```
   if request.method == 'POST':
    title = request.POST.get('title', '')
    content = request.POST.get('text', '')
    author = request.POST.get('author', '')
    now = timezone.now()

   post_article = Article.objects.create(
        article_title=title,
        article_content=content,
        pub_date=now,
        author=author)

    article = ?

    action.send(request.user, verb='posted article', action_object=post_article, target=article)
```

---

As you can see , the user creates an article on POST method and I want to get the title of that new created article and set it as target in my activity stream but I have no idea on how to do it.

Any help would be great.

Comment: `post_article.article_title`?

Comment: By all means, read the tutorial. Django has all tools needed to validate user input, **do. not. save. submitted. data. without. validating. it**. Ever. Use the forms api, or DRF, that's what they're for.

Comment: I just got into it so any advice will be accepted , thanks

Comment: There's no need to use all caps. We can read lower-case just fine, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to get it? You already have it. The title is in `post_article.article_title`.

But of course you don't even need to get it from there, as you already had it in `request.POST['title']`.

Comment: I definitely didn't see , I had tried this but , it's giving this error . Object <class 'str'> is not a Model class.